# Web deploy 2.0 vs. Web Farm Framework 2.0

Tags: iis, webdeploy, web-farm-framework

After reading [Scott Gu's newest post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/20/microsoft-web-farm-framework-2-0.aspx), I wondered how Web Deploy and Web Farm Framework are different?

Comment: See http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/using-web-deploy-for-web-farms

Answer (score 5):

Web deploy is *how* the applications (websites) and server configurations are synchronised between different machines in the farm.

The farm itself is created and managed by WFF - ergo it's not an either/or: WFF relies on Web deploy for part of it's synchronising operation.

Answer (score 3):

In the WebDeploy [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx) ScottGu has stated the below which should clear the confusion:

"Web Deploy can be used together with the Microsoft Web Farm Framework to enable automated deployment across a web-farm.  You can install and configure Web Deploy on a primary server in a Web Farm Framework cluster – and the secondary servers within the web farm cluster will then monitor and clone any applications you deploy with it."

So basically, use WebDeploy to update your primary server in the cluster and the WFF will then replicate the same across the entire cluster.